# How to give an external js plugin the this.$el reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a js file named bars.js. This javascript file contains the code to display the outer structure of the page. So when I do $('#mainContainer').drawBar(); (drawBar() is a function inside the Bars.js) it will draw the outside structure of my page. Now, I am using backbone.js. In the app.js I am calling the $('#mainContainer').drawBar();

So drawBar() function has `<table><tr class='rows_table'><td> ABC</td><td>DEF</td></tr></table>` (this code resides in the bar.js)

So this will append to my 'mainContainer'.

So now, my question is, from app.js I am not able to refer the elements like :
this.$('.rows_table').css("display","block");

rather I have to call it 
$('.rows_table').css("display","block");. Is there a way I can bring this bar.js code in "this.$" reference?

Can i call it this.$('.rows_table')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view you are calling `this.$('.rows_table')` from should be in-charge of the  element.

Each Backbone view has an DOM element that it is in-charge of. If you don't set the element,  it is just an empty `<div>` that is being created by the view.

You can set the element when you create the view by setting the `el` element.

You will need to have a reference to the table element and then:

```
var tableElement = $('table')[0]; // or get the reference in a way specific to your code
var myView = new Backbone.View({
    el : tableElement
});
```

And now you can call `this.$('.rows_table')` from within the view's methods.

Answer (score -1):

`this` is a Backbone.View instance?? If so, you should use `this.$el.find(".rows_table")` instead of `this.$(".rows_table")`

Comment: but with this I will not be able to bind the events. like eg: events:{'click .rows_table':'this.updateTable'}

Comment: I'm not sure about the problem.. maybe you could show us some code?

Comment: Um, [`this.$(...)`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) is shorthand for `this.$el.find(...)`.

Comment: So here I am just using this view as a container to load the Bar.js  in it. This view has no class or id. The index.html has a div with id "mainContainer" and hence in the app.js I do $('#mainContainer').drawBar(); this way the DrawBar() contents are loaded inside my 'mainContainer'. So now how should i use 'this' keywork for fetching the inner elements of the drawBar() created elements from app.js ?